# How long does Upgrade-SPSite takes to upgrade a site collection?

Tags: 2013, upgrade

I am testing upgrade of a site collection to SharePoint 2013. The size of the content database is 225 GB. It has only one site collection.

This is a double hop upgrade. I have upgraded SP2007 sitecollection to SP2010 first.

On SP 2013 the Upgrade-SPSite is running now for 4 days and only 75% is completed.

The database is already cleaned up for document versions and audit log (clean up done in SP2007). The database is also shrinked (in SP 2007).

I analyzed the site upgrade log file to find the elapsed time for various activities.

The process is trying to upgrade 5688 sub sites in the site collection.

For the initial sub sites, the elapsed time is ~20 to 30 seconds. However as the upgrade is progressing the elapsed time is increasing for each subsite to 2 to 3 minutes.

The biggest difference in execution time is for following steps

1. Provisioning the Design Gallery in site

> Provisioning the Design Gallery in site: << URL of a subsite>>
>
> [SPTree Value=SPSite Url= added to dependency cache by lookup
>   [SPTree Value=SPSite Url= added to dependency cache by lookup
>   [SPTree Value=SPSite Url= added to dependency cache by lookup
>   End Upgrade()
>   Begin Commit()
>   End Commit()
>   Begin Dispose()
>   End Dispose()
>   SQL Query Count=48
>   SPRequest Objects=19
>   Execution Time=678.875806841372
>
> Provisioning the Design Gallery in site: <>
>   [SPTree Value=SPSite Url= added to dependency cache by lookup
>   [SPTree Value=SPSite Url= added to dependency cache by lookup
>   [SPTree Value=SPSite Url= added to dependency cache by lookup
>   End Upgrade()
>   Begin Commit()
>   End Commit()
>   Begin Dispose()
>   End Dispose()
>   SQL Query Count=58
>   SPRequest Objects=1348
>   Execution Time=26429.550543435

2. Provisioning oslo.preview file in site

> Provisioning oslo.preview file in site: nontoxic  Site Url: << url of the subsite>>
>
> Successfully provisioned oslo preview master page into the master page gallery.
>   End Upgrade()
>   Begin Commit()
>   End Commit()
>   Begin Dispose()
>   End Dispose()
>   SQL Query Count=6
>   SPRequest Objects=0
>   Execution Time=177.670346370838
>
> Provisioning oslo.preview file in site: hortprac  Site Url: << Url of the subsite>>
>   Successfully provisioned oslo preview master page into the master page gallery.
>   End Upgrade()
>   Begin Commit()
>   End Commit()
>   Begin Dispose()
>   End Dispose()
>   SQL Query Count=15
>   SPRequest Objects=1330
>   Execution Time=33145.8395550272

Comment: I know you are doing this to test the upgrade path to 2013, but it could be a good opportunity to split that many subsites into separate site collections (perhaps, for example in the SP2010 environment) which will help with maintenance in the future.

Comment: Did you specify VersionUpgrade as a parameter? Or just Build-to-build upgrade?

Comment: As another test after this completes, you could try running Test-SPSite to do a site collection health check.  This may highlight any specific issues (other than the large no. subsites).

Comment: Interesting test. If you find the time is increasing as you move through the sub sites, it could mean bad memory management in the upgrade process. It would be worthwhile to try and isolate that site that is taking 33145s and run an upgrade only on that one site?

Comment: Thanks Russell. Yes spliting is one of the option. However spliting will require considerable involvement from the site owners. Throughing new features and behivour with exisiting layout and navigation structure will have better user acceptance. So we planned to upgrade the site collection as it is in the first phase. However for further performance enhancement we will split into multiple site collections.

Comment: @Russell, I am using this script to upgrade. It is with version upgrade.
$site="<<site url>>"    
### VARIABLES ###

$starttime=Get-Date
Write-Host $starttime
 
Upgrade-SPSite $site -VersionUpgrade 

$endtime=Get-Date
Write-Host $endtime

Comment: I looked at the activity monitor for the upgrading database. For the queries related to changing AllDocs, AllWebparts, site features, the process goes in suspended mode with PAGEIOLATCH_XX lock. And those queries are listed in expensive query list.

Answer (score 4):

We upgraded one of our 225GB content databases in roughly 4 hours so 4 days is excessive.  What this actually sounds like is that one of the servers in the mix is running into severe resource issues and is having to swap to disk a lot more than it should.  I'd check all the servers in the farm including the SQL server and make sure that they have adequate free disk space and sufficient RAM.  It is also possible that you are running into a server quota set at some point, either on CPU, RAM or disk space.

If your shop is like many these days, it is possible that the SQL data files are also hosted on a SAN and an improper setting there could easily cause this behavior.

Comment: To add to this, many subwebs (in the thousands) can significantly impact upgrade performance as well.

Comment: Thanks Trevor. Mount-contentdatabe is finishing within 4 hours for my database. However upgrade-spsite for a site collection is taking longer.